# display facebook.com in browser adress bar but display another site content in body

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to display example: `https://www.facebook.com` in my members browser address bar but display another site content in my webpage body.

I want to use `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.facebook.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php [R=301,L]
```

Not work.

Comment: The whole thing sounds dodgy...you can't pass yourself off as facebook.

Comment: "facebook.com" is not a good analogy. Whatever domain you want to have visible in the address bar must be a domain that you own and control and this code must be located wherever that domain resolves to. You obviously do not have control of "facebook.com".

Answer (score 2):

Anybody who tries to visit https://www.facebook.com/ will be directed to Facebook itself - that's controlled by the browser & DNS. Your rewrite rule would only work if you actually had control of the facebook.com domain.

Comment: OK it is understood. But could I use javascript frameset or other display the address of facebook.com in the address bar of the browser but display another content on the same page ??

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="Description">
<meta name="keywords" content="Keyword1, Keyword2">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,0" border="0">
<frame src=" https://facebook.com " frameborder="0">
<frame frameborder="0">
</frameset>
</html>

Comment: @user94406: So, you were literally referring to the domain "facebook.com" - that wasn't just a "for example"?!

Comment: Putting `facebook.com` in a frame would load Facebook in the page, but your own domain in the address bar still. That would be the opposite of what you've asked for.